# Как исправить баг с position: fixed в Chrome на Android при скролле?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Я открываю свой сайт через Chrome на своем телефоне. Делаю так, чтобы появился popup. У меня вместе с popup появляется его полупрозрачный черный фон. Если кликнуть на этот фон, то popup пропадает. Этот фон имеет `position: fixed`.

Так вот. Я открываю, начинаю скроллить, у хрома пропадает адресная строка (уезжает вверх), сайт скроллится, а вот фон стоит на месте, из-за чего внизу у него высотой в эту адресную строку появляется отступ. 
Прикладываю скриншоты. Как мне это исправить?

Сейчас у меня стоит `top: 0`. Я пробовал добавлять еще и `bottom: 0`, но тогда отступ появляется вверху. Пробовал убирать `height: 100%` - не помогло. Да и не очень это классный вариант, так как у меня есть fixed элементы на сайте, где height фиксированный (меню для телефонов, например).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: height:100vh + meta:viewport есть ?

Comment: @НикитаФаст, у меня `height: 100%`. Мета тег вот такой: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>`.

Comment: именно 100vh надо для mobile

Comment: спасибо, помогло